# how to do proper Capitalization validation for textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Im inserting text as a name of member now I've done some code for capitalization of 1st letter...but the problem is that as I try to insert new word between two other words the cursor goes to end of the last word whenever I press the key...

Im dealing with following code...

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
tbOwnerName.Text = textInfo.ToTitleCase(tbOwnerName.Text.ToLower());
tbOwnerName.Select(tbOwnerName.Text.Length, 0);
```

I know there's something wrong in last line code ,but i cant figure it out..so help me out

Comment: I think you can split the text with space as delimiter and then check whether the first letter of each string is upper-case or not, I prefer this validation on textbox_leave event and another validation in submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right before you replace the tbOwnerName.Text, store the current cursor position tbOwnerName.SelectionStart in a variable. Then replace your last line with tbOwnerName.Select(lastPosition,0). What's happening here is replacing Text will take your cursor to the first position, the old Select can handle normal typing (beginning to end) well, but it can't handle typing in the middle.